# Cloudy white film spots on surface of stone sealer

Tags: tile, grout, stone, sealer

After sealing a stone tile surface outdoors, these white cloudy spots appeared within a day or two. They appear more frequently near the grout than the tile, but not exclusively. What caused this, and what can I do to clean it up, if anything?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience, it is excess moisture. The one spot looks like water sat on the sealer before it cured. The remedy is add a bit more sealer to the area, try just enough to dampen the area first on a clean cloth. Make sure it is dry, and stays dry until it cures.

Comment: You're ruling out birds?  :-)

Comment: No lumps...or at least a dark speck.

Comment: Definitely not birds. Not obvious from this one photo, I agree, but looking at some of the other spots it's quite obvious.

Comment: I'll give this a try.

Comment: Seems to help significantly. Not perfect but much better. Thanks